# Setting Icon for Java Program doesn´t work

Tags: java, jframe, icons

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;



public class MainClass extends JFrame {




public static void main(String[] args){


    JFrame myframe = new JFrame("Mein Programm");
    myframe.setSize(600, 400);
    myframe.setVisible(true);
    myframe.add(new JLabel("Label"));


  }

}
```

I try to make a simple java program and I don´t know how to change the java cup icon. I tried several threads from the forum and all of them don´t work for me. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new package/folder called res (resources) with the subfolder icons and put your icon files with different sizes in it. The program will automatically decide at runtime which size is needed, depending on the screen resolution.

```
// Supply the program with different icon sizes for different resolutions
ArrayList<Image> icons = new ArrayList<>();
icons.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/icons/tcc_icon-16x16.png")));
icons.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/icons/tcc_icon-32x32.png")));
icons.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/icons/tcc_icon-64x64.png")));
icons.add(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/icons/tcc_icon-128x128.png")));
setIconImages(icons);
```

Comment: When I add that list to my project, the getClass is red underlined and it says "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object".

Comment: That's because you added it to the Main method. That's not how you should structure the class. Make a default constructor and move all your code from the Main-method in it. In the Main method you should only initialize the new object with _new MainClass();_

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting the icon there. To set it, use the [`JFrame.setIconImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage(java.awt.Image)) method

```
myFrame.setIconImage(yourIcon);
```